# Name for functors preserving and reflecting weak equivalences?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, model-categories

Is there an established name for functors between Quillen model categories (or actually any homotopical category) preserving and reflecting weak equivalences ?

This is kind of the homotopical version of conservative functors (i.e. preserving (of course) and reflecting isomorphisms), so I'm tempted to call them *homotopically conservative* or something. But maybe there already is a name out there ?

Comment: I like the name homotopically conservative!